# What is the supported range for Hive's Timestamp data types

Tags: hive, timestamp, orc

- Hadoop Distro: HDP 2.4.2
- Hive Version: 1.2.1

I have an ORC table `tbl1` having `timestamp` column. I inserted these values:

```
insert into tbl1 values ('0001-01-01 00:00:20.0');
insert into tbl1 values ('9999-01-01 00:00:20.0');
```

I created another ORC table `tbl2` having `timestamp` column. Then I tried:

```
insert into tbl2 select * from tbl1;
```

Data in `tbl2` is corrupted:

```
1754-08-28 22:44:01.128654848
1815-03-31 05:56:28.066277376
```

- Am I using out of range values?
- Is there any specific range for timestamp?

---

This problem is only for `ORC` file format. For other file formats like `textfile`, `avro`, `parquet`, etc it's working fine.

Comment: Issue cannot be reproduce on Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.7.0

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I tested on HDP 2.4.2 Hive 1.2.1

Comment: Also cannot be reproduce on Hadoop 2.7.3.2.5.3.0-37, Hive 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz This may be replicated on Cloudera distro. Check my answer for Apache Hive.

Comment: Cool :-) ......

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Thanks for trying this on CDH..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive vectorization is enabled in my case.

```
hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
```

This is an issue due to vectorized execution.

*It is fixed in 1.3.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0*

Check [HIVE-9862](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9862) and [wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=34838326#VectorizedQueryExecution-Limitations) for more details.

To use vectorized query execution, you must store your data in ORC format. That's why the error is coming only in ORC file format.